# mingw32: Bad function name - Kali 2.0

Tags: mingw32

I'm fairly new to Linux, so go easy please.

I am trying to install the Ming C Compiler on Kali 2.0

My first attempt was to do a simple "apt-get install mingw32" but the package cannot be located. I downloaded the .tar file from their website, unpacked it and in the README it says to run "sh x86-mingw32-build.sh --unattended mingw32" to install it, but when running that I receive a Syntax Error: bad function name message at the x86-mingw32-build.sh.functions file.

Any idea how to correct this Syntax Error? Any easier way to install the Ming C Compiler on Kali 2.0?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

I've just been solving it successfully on Linux Mint 18 MATE 32 bit. :)
I hope it works on other linux systems too!

So:
After you made the *x86-mingw32-build.sh* file executable, with:

```
cd x86-mingw32-build-1.0
chmod +x x86-mingw32-build.sh
```

Then just use ***bash* (instead of sh)** to run the script:

```
cd x86-mingw32-build-1.0
bash x86-mingw32-build.sh
```

That's it! :D It is easy, but badly the documentation writes that you have to run it with 'sh'. BUT NO! It only worked for me *EXACTLY* with **BASH**.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message there should be somewhere a part with :130  or another number, thats the line number of the function causing problems (in x86-mingw32-build.sh.functions)
And thats the forbidden name.